# Cast of pointers to template classes

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

To hide implementation details from users of the interface and to avoid wide-spread use of templatized functions I thought of the following concept:

// data.h

```
#ifndef DATA_H_
#define DATA_H_

#include <cstddef>

template <size_t N = 0>
class Data
{
   public:
      const size_t n;
      size_t values[N];
      Data<N>();
};

#endif // DATA_H_
```

// data.cpp

```
#include "data.h"

template <size_t N> Data<N>::Data()
:
   n(N),
   values()
{
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
   {
      values[i] = i;
   }
}

template class Data<1u>;
template class Data<2u>;
```

// list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

class List
{
   private:
      std::shared_ptr<void> data;
   public:
      List(const size_t);
      void printData() const;
};

#endif // LIST_H_
```

// list.cpp

```
#include "list.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "data.h"

List::List(const size_t n)
:
   data()
{
   switch ( n )
   {
      case 1u:
         data = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(std::make_shared<Data<1u>>());
         break;
      case 2u:
         data = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(std::make_shared<Data<2u>>());
         break;
      default:
         throw std::runtime_error("not instantiated..");
   }
}

void List::printData() const
{
   auto obj = std::static_pointer_cast<Data<>>(data);  // my question is about this
   std::cout << obj->n << ": ";
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < obj->n; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << obj->values[i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << "\n";
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i <= 2; ++i )
    {
       try
       {
          List list(i);
          list.printData();
       }
       catch ( ... )
       {
          return 1;
       }
    }
}
```

I know that some may think of this as horrible design. Please don't discuss this here, unless you have a brilliant alternative.

My question is about the line `auto obj = std::static_pointer_cast<Data<>>(data);` in `List::printData()`.  It feels kind of unsafe. Is there a **guarantee** that the correct instantiation is used? `g++-4.6.3` does not give a warning for this code and it prints the expected values.

Comment: I hope you realize the `const size_t n` in your data class is entirely unneeded. You have the value as part of your template parameter list, namely **`N`**.

Comment: @WhozCraig what about `obj->n`? how to do that with the template parameter?

Comment: std::static_pointer_cast<Data<>> will always cast to Data<0> ... is that what you're asking ?

Comment: "It feels kind of unsafe. Is there a guarantee that the correct instantiation is used?" -- why would the implementation magically know the right type? No, it's not safe, don't do it.

Comment: You would add a method that returns `N`.

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah, what he (you) said. =P

Comment: @WhozCraig / juanchopanza  what's the benefit? this field needs to be accessed often, so why add a function call?

Comment: The benefit is that you don't need a data member.

Comment: @juanchopanza Captain Obvious, but seriously: why get rid of a data member at the cost of a buttload of function calls?

Comment: The dysfunction of that cast in itself is reason. The premise of having a untyped pointer masking a variant-typed declaration exposes the problem with this. There is no reason for the template to begin with. You would be better off using a std::vector<> which sizes at runtime (which is exactly what you're trying to do via a auto). Your cast in question is casting a Data<N> to a Data<0>, which, after deduction, are two different `types`. Don't do that. If you want dynamic sizing use a class that *does* so.

Comment: Because it takes up space unnecessarily and you actively have to make sure it is set correctly. And I'm not sure what butload of function calls you are talking about, expect possibly the ones that replace a buttload of data member accesses.

Comment: @juanchopanza - the data member is needed because he's tricking the type system into doing something crazy.  If he lets the type system say what n is then it'll be 0 in his print function.

Comment: @WhozCraig It's a performance reason: N is usually very small and the app is twice as fast without `std::vector`.

Comment: @stefan - I very much doubt that.  Perhaps you're using vector incorrectly.  Are you reserving the size?

Comment: @CrazyEddie I know what I'm doing, I didn't use vector wrong.

Comment: @Yakk Compare http://ideone.com/cnWpQf with http://ideone.com/ak8gLZ Just get over it. Static information is good, vectors aren't perfect

Comment: @Yakk It's not apples and oranges and I still didn't use it wrong. The sample code is an over-simplification of my actual code which involves more fields, but nonetheless the code shows that std::vector is not perfect in all cases. If you still think it's better, demonstrate it with a code in which the vector is wrapped in a class that exhibits the same funtionality as TestStatic. **You can't**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It's unsafe.  Any time you cast through a `void*` you run the risk of UB.  The compiler isn't warning you about it because it no longer has the type information necessary to do so.  It is thus on you to cast to the correct type, which you're not doing.

Technically speaking, you're causing undefined behavior here.  My bet is, however, that it'll usually work.  It's not unlike some of the hokey crap you have to do in C all the time.

The reason it will work is that the binary layout of your instances will likely be the same.  First the 'n', which you DO need to have if you're doing this nasty trick, followed by the beginning of an array.

If you ever do this outside of the realm of pointers then you're going to screw yourself.

The only reason your object is correctly deleted is that shared_ptr creates a default deleter at point of creation, thus it knows how to delete the correct type.  Any of the other smart pointers would cause all kinds of BS if you tried this.

Edit:

Now, a much better method of doing this is to forego the use of the type system to size your array.  You really want a runtime allocated array, use the runtime system to create it!  You're creating it on the free store anyway, so you're not getting ANY benefit from abusing the type system like this.  You can have safe, predictable, standard behavior if you just allocate your array based on the size passed to your list constructor.

Comment: If it's anything like C99, there will be memory layout guarantees which allow you to access the leading common fields via a different type (useful for `struct sockaddr` and friends), but I'm not sure this is guaranteed to work for arrays (let alone zero-length arrays). In any case, I strongly suspect that subscripting a zero-length array is UB (unless C++ treats it like C99's variable-length arrays).

Comment: @tc - yeah, I don't know either.  I doubt C++ treats it like a variable length array.  In fact there are or where more restrictions on array access in C++ than C (such as the whole &array[one_past_end] thing).  At any rate, it's a major abuse of the type system and bound to cause problems...if only in the fact that team members will constantly be going WTF 0_o when they look at it.  I certainly don't encourage it, but I think it will mostly, usually work.

Comment: I also don't see how it's practical, since you have to know all the required list sizes at compile time...

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a static_cast that is parsed at compile time. So what you're telling the compiler is:

```
auto obj = std::static_pointer_cast<Data<>>(data);
```

`static_pointer_cast` the variable **`data`** to type **`std::shared_ptr<Data<>>`**.
And by default (as you declared in the template prototype) `Data<>` means `Data<0>`.

So you'll always get the same type of `shared_pointer`.

What you can do, is make an interface, and get the size in runtime.

```
class IData 
{
  virutal size_t GetDataSize() = 0;
}

template <size_t N = 0>
class Data : public IData
{
   public:
      const size_t n;
      size_t values[N];
      Data<N>();
      virtual size_t GetDataSize() override { return N; }
};
```

Then hold a list to the interface type and just use `data->GetDataSize();`

Besides, don't put the template implementation in the .cpp file, they need to be seen where they're used.

Comment: Putting template implementation in a cpp file is perfectly appropriate if that's the only place it's used.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Yeap, but it's not where it's used in this case.